# What is the Font Used in Pokemon Conquest?

Tags: pokemon-conquest

What's the font used in Pokemon Conquest's dialogue? More specifically, since I assume it's some proprietary font compiled in the game, where have I seen it before? It looked extremely familiar as soon as I saw it.

Here's an example:

[image: pokemon conquest dialogue]

My first thought was Final Fantasy Tactics Advance. I compared the letterforms, and they do seem to be mostly similar but with some slight differences. Even though the differences are subtle, the *look* and *feel* of the fonts looks visibly different, so I'm wondering if there's another game that I'm thinking of.

**Final Fantasy Tactics Advance**: The lowercase `a` and `t` look identical. But the tail of the FFTA `e` curves up whereas the tail of the Pokemon `e` lies flat; the FFTA `i` has a very subtle serif, whereas the Pokemon `i` does not.

[image: Final Fantasy Tactics Advance]

Comment: Hey, rubergly.  I've voted to close this as there's no real answer we can provide; most likely, it's something specific to the company and not any public font.

Comment: Given that game identification is off-topic, I would think that font identification is even less so.  Sorry!  Check out the [FAQ] and feel free to ask any other questions you might have that would be a better fit.

Comment: @MatthewRead I'm not so sure I agree that this is at all off-topic. And if it is, it should have nothing to do with the separate issues with game identification. [I've bloviated about it on meta, so I'd appreciate your thoughts.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This will answer any Pokémon font related questions you have](http://projectpokemon.org/forums/showthread.php?5799-Essential-Pokemon-related-Fonts). This details the various fonts used in game with links to download TTFs for each. The one you're after appears to be labelled as 'Pokémon D/P/Pt', fifth down on the list.

Additional variations of these fonts from other games in the series from a variety of platforms [can be found on DarkAngelX's DeviantArt](https://web.archive.org/web/20121101174921/http://darkangelx.deviantart.com/art/Pokemon-Script-Collection-V2-22208470).

Comment: It's just the font from the most recent main series games.

Comment: it appears it is, but the way main-series Pokemon games style text with the lower-right drop-shadow makes it look very different (compare to http://idleblogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/victini.jpg)

Comment: @rubergly I get a 500 internal server error from that link - ah nevermind, you're missing a www. :)

Comment: @rubergly I see what you mean, yeah they're the same font or *very very* close - the drop shadow definitely confuses things slightly.

Answer (score -3):

As I was looking for a font similiar to Pokémon's dialogue i found out that GulimChe looks a lot like it. You should have this font on your computer, otherwise you might find it online. :)

Comment: This answer is obviously incorrect. GulimChe is not even an English font - it's for Korean.