# What is the font used in Europa Universalis 4?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

What is the font used in Europa Universalis 4?

[image: Screenshot of Europa Universalis]

Comment: I've downvoted this question, because it's not really on topic. It's not tagged with a game, plus we don't really do fonts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about game design and specially fonts.

Comment: Hell if I knew how to tag it properly, but I replied just in case this is useful for someone to know. The screen shot is from EU3, but the same engine is used for more Paradox games.

Comment: @DavidYell there are a few other questions about fonts that are considered on topic. (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76720/what-is-the-font-used-in-pokemon-conquest and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161926/what-font-is-used-in-pokemon-x-and-y )

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Yeah, if I'd said it was on topic, someone would have said it wasn't. I gambled wrong today it seems ;)

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden this is why it's better to prepare for the argument you are anticipating ;)

Answer (score 7):

The Clausewitz engine (the screen shot is of one of the games using it, Europa Universalis III) has fonts as bitmaps saved in the `gfx\fonts\` sub-folder of the game's installation folder. For mods, it's in the same folder of the mod's sub-folder.

Answer (score 3):

[I ran the font through Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/list?1%20id%2020%202JN4%201%202XIH%201%205YF%202%202XII%202%20P4I%202%201O1%203%203FGF%203%203PJ%203%202VK%203%2023G9%203%2029TS%203%205GQ%203%202SB2%203%20W5%203%208Z0%203%208OO%203%20GHJ%204%201ZW%204%20214%204%2042W%204%20245O%204%201ZX%204%20FPB%204%20HEO%204%20CL%204%20F5%204%201PN%204%20O4M%204%206LK%204%204VU%205) and I this font is, IMVHO, Adobe Garamond. The match, especially with the number forms like 4 and 9, is basically perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can find names of all the fonts in `.fnt` files in `/gfx/fonts`. Just open a file in question with a text editor.